# In this code what does resolve and reject do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning about promises, I asked the question just to clear my mind. I think I understand what it does but can't put it into words.
I would really appreciate if someone explained the first 2 lines of this code. Lets says we called the function with a list of car models.

```
       function superSecretOrder(items) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       const random = Math.random() * 1000
       setTimeout(function () {
       resolve([...items].sort())
       }, random)
        })
         }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters

Comment: The anonymous function you pass to `new Promise()` is called by the JS engine; when it calls the function it passes a resolve and reject function. By writing a function with two arguments, you can use these engine-provided functions to resolve / reject the Promise. - The mental switch necessary to "get" this is to go from *calling* a function *provided* by JS to *writing* a function that is *called* by JS.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve is the callback for a promise's return type. You can then access the value using `.then(...)`, example:

```js
function superSecretOrder(items) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const random = Math.random() * 1000
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve([...items].sort())
    }, random)
  })
}

const orderedCardsPromise = superSecretOrder(['b', 'a']);
orderedCardsPromise.then(orderedCards => {
  // After a random amount of time set by `const random = Math.random() * 1000`
  console.log(orderedCards); // ['a', 'b']
});
```